# Change single/multiple character to another single character

Tags: python, string, replace, character

For instance, I have a string like this:

```
my_string = 'a hello aaaaa hi aaaaaaa bye bbb'
```

I want to change `'a'` or `'a'`s to `'b'`. So output I want is:

```
changed_string = 'b hello b hi b bye bbb'
```

I tried use replace and then making multiple `'b'`s to single `'b'`, but then it would effect multiple `'b'`s that were originally in the string.

I don't want an answer like do the first n characters.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> my_string = 'a hello aaaaa hi aaaaaaa bye bbb'
>>> re.sub(r'a+', 'b', my_string)
'b hello b hi b bye bbb'
```

Comment: sorry to ask you again, but i have problem when i'm converting period(.) to something else.(for instance, b)
if i use re.sub(r'.+', 'b', my_string)
the result is b... what can i do about this???

Comment: @H.Choi That's because `.` is a special character which mactches any character except newline by default. Escape it with a backslash like `\.+`. You can see all the special chars here: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html. Also accept my answer if it helped you :D

Answer (score 2):

use regular expression.

depending on your tools, it could be a one-liner or 2-3 line of code.

with vim

```
s/a+/b/g
```

--

ohhh, didn't notice it was python. see jamylak's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without using regex you could do this, although I would rather use regex since it's much clearer and faster in this case.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> my_string = 'a hello aaaaa hi aaaaaaa bye bbb'
>>> ''.join(''.join(g) if k != 'a' else 'b' for k, g in groupby(my_string))
'b hello b hi b bye bbb'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> mystring = 'a hello aaaaa hi aaaaaaa bye bbb'
>>> ' '.join('b' if set(i)==set(['a']) else i for i in mystring.split())
'b hello b hi b bye bbb'
```

Note that while this works with your example, it will not work with strings where the repeated character is part of a word, such as `'aaaaaz'` - It will leave such words untouched, Which may or may not be desirable...

Comment: no need for a list comprehension here, remove the `[`, `]` to make it a generator. edit: nvm I don't think it would be that inefficient but regex is certainly faster